# How to arrange top-level node items in a dijit Tree via drag and drop

Tags: drag-and-drop, tree, dojo

I have a `dijit.Tree` backed by a `ForestStoreModel` that uses a custom data store to provide the data.  It works well, but I want to provide the ability for the user to rearrange the top-level items (and only the top level) items via the dojo drag-and-drop facility.

The problem is the the `ForestStoreModel::pasteItem` function checks to see if item is a child of the root and then passes a `null` to the `TreeStoreModel::pasteItem`.

```
pasteItem: function(/*Item*/ childItem, /*Item*/ oldParentItem, /*Item*/ newParentItem, /*Boolean*/ bCopy, /*int?*/ insertIndex){
        // summary:
        //      Move or copy an item from one parent item to another.
        //      Used in drag & drop
        if(oldParentItem === this.root){
            if(!bCopy){
                // It's onLeaveRoot()'s responsibility to modify the item so it no longer matches
                // this.query... thus triggering an onChildrenChange() event to notify the Tree
                // that this element is no longer a child of the root node
                this.onLeaveRoot(childItem);
            }
        }
        dijit.tree.TreeStoreModel.prototype.pasteItem.call(this, childItem,
            oldParentItem === this.root ? null : oldParentItem,
            newParentItem === this.root ? null : newParentItem,
            bCopy,
            insertIndex
        );
        if(newParentItem === this.root){
            // It's onAddToRoot()'s responsibility to modify the item so it matches
            // this.query... thus triggering an onChildrenChange() event to notify the Tree
            // that this element is now a child of the root node
            this.onAddToRoot(childItem);
        }
    }
```

The `TreeStoreModel` does not update the underlying data store if the passed parent items are null and the `onLeaveRoot` and `onAddToRoot` events do not pass in the `insertIndex`, so I cannot use them to update my data store (which seems like it would be a bit backwards, anyway).

At this point I think the only viable option is to extend the `ForestStoreModel` in order to allow me to set the synthetic `$root$` item to a compatible data store object and allow the `ForestStoreModel` to pass it, unaltered, through to the `TreeStoreModel`.

Are there other way of approaching this problem?

**Update**

The eventual solution turned out to be even simpler than suggested.  My `ForestStoreModel` is already a custom class because I am actually using the dojo 1.6 ObjectStore as a data source, so I can pass the desired index in the `options` argument to the object store `put` method.  The fix was just a one-liner as I let the parent class take care of calling `onLeaveRoot` and `onAddRoot`:

```
pasteItem: function(/*Item*/ childItem, /*Item*/ oldParentItem, /*Item*/ newParentItem, /*Boolean*/ bCopy, /*int?*/ insertIndex){
    // Handle drag & drop at the root level
    if (oldParentItem === this.root && newParentItem === this.root){
        this.store.put(childItem, { index: insertIndex });
    } 
    this.inherited(arguments);
}
```

Comment: That update should have been an answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You will need to subclass `ForestTreeModel`, you can't escape that. But, you'll only need to override `pasteItem`. You can't pass the synthetic root to the `TreeStoreModel` because it doesn't know anything about it.

If you need to modify the underlying data store, you're better off calling `this.store.setValues()` directly. That should trigger the `onSetItem` event and in turn call `_requeryTop()` for you, which will fetch the roots from the underlying store in whatever order you arrange them, so be sure to reflect that in your modification.

```
dojo.declare('MyForestTreeModel', [ dijit.tree.ForestTreeModel ], {
  pasteItem: function(childItem, oldParentItem, newParentItem, bCopy, insertIndex) {
    if (oldParentItem == this.root && newParentItem == this.root) {
      if (!bCopy) { this.onLeaveRoot(childItem); }
      // modify the underlying store somehow so the call to _requeryTop() fetches
      // the items in the correct order.
      // (you decide what's 'order' and what new_order() returns)
      this.store.setValues(childItem, 'order', new_order(insertIndex));
      this.onAddRoot(childItem);
    } else {
      // call super
      this.inherited(arguments);
    }
  }
});
```

The other, easier way, is to manipulate `this.root.children` yourself and then emit the event `onChildrenChange` to notify the views. Beware, that method won't persist the order.

```
dojo.declare('MyForestTreeModel', [ dijit.tree.ForestTreeModel ], {
  pasteItem: function(childItem, oldParentItem, newParentItem, bCopy, insertIndex) {
    if (oldParentItem == this.root && newParentItem == this.root) {
      if (!bCopy) { this.onLeaveRoot(childItem); }
      // manipulate this.root.children to reorder childItem
      // remove child from the current position
      var children = dojo.filter(this.root.children, function(x) {
        return x != childItem;
      });
      // and insert it into the new index
      children.splice(insertIndex, 0, childItem);
      this.root.children = children;
      // notify views
      this.onChildrenChanged(this.root, children);
      this.onAddRoot(childItem);
    } else {
      // call super
      this.inherited(arguments);
    }
  }
});
```

Comment: I do need to modify the data store, so I'll try a version based on your first suggestion.